# gcc using the wrong ldfile for system llibrary

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I am tryin to compile an opensource project for ARM (Xvisor) but apparently gcc is using the wrong ldfile to link the library `libncurse` indeed when I compile, I got the following error:

```
/usr/gnat/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.1/ld: cannot find libncurses.so.5
```

And `ldconfig` seems to have the library in it

```
ldconfig -p | grep "curse"
libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5
libncurses.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
libncurses.so.5 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
libncurses.so.5 (libc6) => /lib32/libncurses.so.5
```

I don't understand why gcc is using the gnat ldfile instead of the system ldfile.

Comment: You are probably trying to link host's library to cross-compiled app.

Comment: @arrowd Do you know I can link the right library? I don't understand why  on Debian it worked and not on Ubuntu. How do I link the library and how can i recognize the lib file in the project

Comment: arrowd Indeed it seems to come from the cross compilation. The Makefile doesn't succeed to read the local exported variable $CROSS_COMPILE. So the Makefile use gcc instead of arm-eabi-gcc. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: It seems you're invoking host compiler. Instead you should invoke cross compiler, something like `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. Also, you might need cross binutils. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/250721/127235

Comment: Ok Thanks guys. Indeed the makefile was incorrect. So I corrected It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall build-essential package

```
sudo apt-get remove build-essential && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

`/usr/gnat` is not the main directory for the system library

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that Makefile was using `gcc` tool instead of the cross compile gcc:`arm-eabi-gcc`